# I can't open mail via Launcher URL in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, url-launcher

My Code is not working. Do not opening email via this code. Their shows a null error.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add this in AndroidManifest.xml just above of application

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUERY_ALL_PACKAGES" />

<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
    <!-- If your app opens https URLs -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="http" />
    </intent>
    <!-- If your app opens https URLs -->
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <data android:scheme="https" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

Comment: Same Error thrown

Answer (score 0):

In launch you are converting it to a string whereas it would require a uri to be launched. Remove .toString from the launch method

```dart
launch(emailLaunchUri);
```

Comment: Another Error ! - https://prnt.sc/CCXTfVBuJ5N-

Comment: Url launcher's launch method should take a uri only. Which version of url launcher are you using? Also if you hover on the launch method which class does it show?

Comment: I'm using the latest url launcher version. when i hover on the launch method this https://prnt.sc/EamMKFYyedMg is shown to me. i also added necessary queries to the manifest.xml file.... but not working...

Comment: You are hovering on uri. Hover on launch

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ijo8HUP0r0t4

Comment: The launch method that is calling is defined in main.dart. Not from url launcher package. Delete that method